# Android - Eclipse: "Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token"

Tags: java, android, arrays, button, download

How do I set an array to change the URL of an Async download task for multiple butons?
This isn't working and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
final String[] dlUrl = new String[]{"www.google.com/document.pdf", "www.google.com/document2.pdf", "www.google.com/document3.pdf"};{ 
for(int k = 0; i < dlUrl.length; i++) { 
    final String dlUrl = downloadFile.execute([k]); 


}
```

I am trying to have it change the following code section:

```
private void startDownload() {
    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
    downloadFile.execute("http://www.google.com/doc.pdf");

}
```

And the Async Task itself:

```
class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
```

I have a similar array that picks up button presses, I want to try to add this to it... Any ideas?

```
final OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() { 
     public void onClick(View v){ 
         switch(v.getId()){  
         case R.id.sec1:  
            break; 
         case R.id.sec2: 
            break; 
         case R.id.sec3: 
            break; 
         } 
     } 
};
final int[] btnIds = new int[]{R.id.sec1, R.id.sec2, R.id.sec3};{ 
for(int i = 0; i < btnIds.length; i++) { 
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById (btnIds[i]); 
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener); 
}
```

Comment: Learning Java and android through trial and error is difficult but I appreciate all your help guys!

Comment: Do you have a `;{` instead of just `;` at the end of the `final int[] btnIds` is it a typo only here or is it also in your code?

Comment: It's not clear where in your code you get an exception and what is not working. Also you seem to ask multiple things in the same question that are not necessarily related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final String[] dlUrl = new String[]{"www.google.com/document.pdf",
                                    "www.google.com/document2.pdf",
                                    "www.google.com/document3.pdf"};{ 

for(int k = 0; i < dlUrl.length; i++) { 
    final String dlUrl = downloadFile.execute([k]); 


}
```

should probably be something more like

```
final String[] dlUrl = new String[]{"www.google.com/document.pdf",
                                    "www.google.com/document2.pdf",
                                    "www.google.com/document3.pdf"}; // { removed

for(int k = 0; k < dlUrl.length; k++) { 
               ^

    final String currentUrl = dlUrl[k];
                              ^^^^^^^^

    downloadFile.execute(currentUrl); 
}
```

---

Regarding your own comment:

> *Learning Java and android through trial and error is difficult*

...and an extremely bad idea I must add.

Comment: ...and an extremely bad idea I must add..... Any ideas how I should go about learning?  I am more of a visual learner.. Anyway, great solution Ill give it a shot thanks!

Comment: also, note that the async task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

Comment: @ Raiv - I am only looking for executing it one at a time but I will have a page that shows about thirty buttons.  I don't want the same code copied thirty times with just two vairables changed which is why I'm trying to learn this.  Are you saying that won't work?

Comment: I say "create new instance of DownloadFile task for every file you actually download", all other will be ok.